# SymmetricDS Two Way Synchronization Double Insert

Tags: data-synchronization, symmetricds

I have `server` node and `client` node. They do two way synchronization on a table and also both have `sync_on_incoming_batch = 1`.

Let say, table structure is `(id, name)`.

The scenario is:

1. `server` insert data `(1, 'a')`
2. `client` insert data `(1, 'b')`
3. `server` send batch of `(1, 'a')` to `client`
4. `client` send batch of `(1, 'b')` to `server`
5. Now, `server` has data `(1, 'b')` and `client` has data `(1, 'a')`

Questions are:

1. After `server` received `(1, 'b')`, why `server` cannot route again the data to `client`? It's detected by `node_id = -1` in `sym_outgoing_batch` on `server`. Vice versa on `client`.
2. How to sync data based on most recent data? So in this case, the result is `(1, 'b')` in all node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `sync_on_incoming_batch` is telling symmetricDs not to route back data to the source node
2. add conflict detection with resolution strategy [newer wins](http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.7/html/user-guide.html#_conflicts)